# ImageMagick compose:args="" to Magick++ API

Tags: c++, image-processing, imagemagick, magick++

I am trying to convert the following ImageMagick command to Magick++:

```
convert input-1.jpg input-2.jpg -compose blend -define compose:args="25,75" -composite result.jpg
```

I am having difficulty with `-define compose:args="25,75"`, I cannot find its equivalent in Magick++. Without the `compose:args=`  part, the Magick++ code is as follows:

```
Magick::Image input1, input2;
input1.read("input-1.jpg");
input2.read("input-2.jpg");
input1.composite(input2, 0,0, BlendCompositeOp);
```

**Can anyone please explain the `compose:args` part to me or better yet tell me its Magick++ equivalent?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to define the image `artifact` on the inbound composite image.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <Magick++.h>

using namespace Magick;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    InitializeMagick(argv[0]);
    Image alpha, beta;
    alpha.read("wizard:");
    beta.read("logo:");
    // -define compose:args="25,75"
    beta.artifact("compose:args", "25,74");
    alpha.composite(beta, 0, 0, BlendCompositeOp);
    alpha.write("/tmp/out.jpg");
    return 0;
}
```

[image: compose:args with Magick++]

Comment: Thanks a million. I was at the point where I was adding "Artifact" functions to Magick++ source and compiling the whole ImageMagick. :p

Comment: I have one more question if you are willing to answer. :)

Comment: Thanks for the positive feedback @MarkSetchell, and Zindarod feel free to post a new question, or comment here if you need additional detail.

Comment: @emcconville http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34329954/imagemagick-result-differ-from-magick

Comment: @emcconville Am wondering what version of Magick++ is this.... I dont see any "artifact" method in the Image class I am working with.....

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ It's still available. The [header signature](https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/blob/master/Magick%2B%2B/lib/Magick%2B%2B/Image.h#L621) hasn't been altered in 5 years.