# ImageMagick result differ from Magick++

Tags: c++, image-processing, imagemagick, blending, magick++

I have 3 images: *[source.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4r0bN.jpg), [saturated.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cz1NV.jpg)* and *[mask.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ugfK.jpg)*, I want to blend the *source.jpg* and *saturated.jpg* using the *mask.jpg*.

When I use the ImageMagick's *convert* command:

```
convert source.jpg saturated.jpg mask.jpg -compose over -composite result.jpg
```

I get this [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dP2kP.jpg).

But when I do the same with Magick++:

```
Magick::Image source,saturated,mask;
source.read("source.jpg");
saturated.read("saturated.jpg");
mask.read("mask.jpg");
source.clipMask(mask);
source.composite(saturated,0,0,OverCompositeOp);
```

I get this [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ze0MU.jpg).

**Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?**

Comment: @emcconville If you could take a look at this question please.

Comment: I am fairly sure you need to convert `mask` to greyscale before you use it, and maybe add a matte (alpha channel) to `source`, and maybe invert the mask, so at least the first and maybe the second and third of the following lines... `mask.type( Magick::GrayscaleType );` and `source.matte(true);` and `mask.negate();`.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Alpha channel has nothing to with it as both source and saturated images are jpegs and I am just adding one over the other. Mask should not be negated because it would reverse the white and black areas and the mask image here is used as a guide to which pixels in the saturated image should be used in which not be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This gets pretty close to the command line version:

```
#include <Magick++.h> 
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 
using namespace Magick; 

int main(int argc,char **argv) 
{ 
   InitializeMagick(*argv);
   Magick::Image source,saturated,mask;
   source.read("source.jpg");
   saturated.read("saturated.jpg");
   mask.read("mask.jpg");
   mask.type( Magick::GrayscaleType );
   mask.negate();
   source.mask(mask);
   source.composite(saturated,0,0,OverCompositeOp);
   source.write("mppresult.jpg");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My mistake was that I was using clipMask() instead of mask(). Because a mask() function does not exist in the documentation. :) But secondly, I don't understand why you are negating the mask. Does ImageMagick negate masks internally?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know - I will defer to Eric (@emcconville) who is bound to know.

Comment: Thanks you for your time.

Comment: Great answer Mark! Zindarod, `clipMask` & `mask` are both leveraged for many subroutines on the pixel cache, and perhaps that's why the documentation is easy to confuse. The `clipMask` & `clipPath` are more specific to virtual pixels and drawing tasks. The `mask` method is correct for your application. Other option would be to composite as `CopyOpacityCompositeOp` over the `saturated` image, but Mark's approach is cleaner (i.e. easier for you to remember what the code is doing).

Comment: @emcconville Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Do you know how to word wrap the annotations in Magick++? I can post the code that I have done so far if you need.

Comment: @emcconville The above question for you too if you've time please.

Comment: Just post a new question - questions are free :-)

Comment: @MarkSetchell http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34352420/how-to-add-word-wrapping-to-texts-in-magick